# How to patch this hole in exposed foundation

Tags: foundation, hole

I guess the first question is, should I even worry about it? From what I can tell there's not a deep hole that an animal could enter in -- I felt around, and basically what you can see in the picture is the extent of it. I only noticed it for the first time because there's been a storage box sitting there from the previous owner since I bought the place.

Opening is ~ 10" long and 3" tall, 2 inches in depth.

Should I fill it with foam? Cover it?

Aesthetics aren't a big priority. This spot is unlikely to get a lot of water coming at it.

[image]

Comment: Picture? That would help

Comment: yep sorry I had one and forgot to attach it when I first submitted

Comment: I would definitely fill it as its posdible there are cracks or holes leading further into the basement or house.

Comment: it looks like the remains of an old foundation-attached staircase, now covered up by a building extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To plug or not to plug? If it's not leaking the weather into somewhere you don't want it, or causing anguish every tome you see it, there's no need to address this hole.

Leaving it open does however run the risk that some local wildlife may decide to make this little cave their home.

To fill it mortar is probably the best approach,  get some pre-mixed (dry) mortar and some concrete bonding agent read the instructions and have at it.

As you're going for a vertical finish you'll probably want a stiffer than usual mix, so use less water and mix it on a board instead of in a bucket. When it seems about right for making sand castles that's the right consistency.

Comment: thanks. Your comment on the other one is helpful too -- batches meant doing it in small portions, you're right, I don't want to have to keep at it off and on for a long period. What does the concrete bonding agent do? I mean, the obvious... but why do you recommend in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Mix up a bit of mortar (stiff, not runny) and pack it in there. Patch masonry with masonry, not foam.

Comment: I've never used mortar. Can I just use a regular bucket to mix up a small batch? For a vertical hole like that, if it's stiff/not runny as you're saying will it hold pretty well? That should probably be the guide for how stiff I make it, I should feel like it's not going to sag down?

Comment: Directions for mixing will be on the bag. Just use a little less water. It will be hard to mix, but persevere. And build it up in 4 or 6 batches.

Comment: @RohitGupta what do you mean when you say "build it up in 4 or 6 batches"?

Comment: Yes, you can mix a small quantity in a bucket, but if you're making a stiff mix it may be easier to mix on a board using a trowel to stir it.   6 batches is a whole- weekend project, I would just put a board against it to prevent it from slumping.

Comment: I meant, do it in 6 lots, waiting for previous lot to dry a bit.  This will stop slumping..  Or use a board as mentioned by Jasen